# JavaScript closure that returns a function

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function funcA(){
  var name = "jack";
  console.log(name);
  return function(){
    name = name + " plus";
    console.log(name);
  };
}
var funB = funcA();
funB()

// expected result: "jack" and "jack plus"
```

I am confused why runnnig `var funB = funcA();` only outputs `"jack"`?

Why doesn't the second sentence output? Why must it be run a second time to output as intended?

Comment: What do you mean by "compile"? Your code works as expected. Could you be more specific which part confuses you?

Comment: Let ignore the funB()，if I only call funcA()，the result is "jack"。But why the return sentence didn't work? I predict it will output "jack plus"

Comment: it does return a function object.

Comment: You predict it wrong. By the time you call `console.log` `name` is still `"jack"` simply because the return statement was not even executed up to the moment. And even after return you need to call a "thunk" you have returned to modify `name` variable.

Comment: got it! thank you!!

Comment: Function will execute only when we call the function. So that you get expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It works, try to run this:

```js
function funcA(){
  var name = "jack";
  console.log(name);
  return function(){
    name = name + " plus";
    console.log(name);
  };
}
var funB = funcA();
funB();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var funB = funcA();
```

it means funcA is executed,and funcA only returns an anonymous function. It won't execute this function without "()".

Answer (score 0):

When you call `funcB = funcA();` what it does is run `funcA()` i.e. `console.log(name);` and then assign the return the anonymous function on line 4. This assign the return function to the funcB (like we do `var someName = function(){ // do something}` ). So, to run the function you need to call `funcB();`

```js
function funcA(){
        var name = "jack";
        console.log(name);
        return function(){
            name = name + " plus";
            console.log(name);
        };
    }
    
    var funcB = funcA();
    //Output:- jack

    console.log(funcB);
    /*Output:- f (){
                   name = name + " plus";
                   console.log(name);
               }
    */
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call funcA() "var funB = funcA()". It logs "jack" then it returns a function. If you return a function, it does not automatically run it first. You only run it when you call it "funB();".